# Issue with Migrator Validation command

Tags: azure-devops, data-migration

I am running the migrator tool to validate a collection.  It completes and then errors out.  Looking for help on the error:

> Execution Time: 0:00:27.6966038 Output Folder:   C:\ Collection -
> Name\20210527_142408
>
> Support for importing from Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1.1 has
> been removed. If you're currently on Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update
> 1.1, you will need to upgrade your on-premises server to Azure DevOps Server 2020 or Azure DevOps Server 2020.0.1
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
> null. Parameter name: tenantName    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.ArgumentUtility.CheckStringForNullOrEmpty(String
> stringVar, String stringVarName, Boolean trim, String
> expectedServiceArea)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Import.IdentityImportValidation.GetAadIdentityMapper(DataImportValidationContext
> context, String tenantName)    at
> TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.RunValidations(Boolean
> requireNetwork, Boolean validateFiles)    at
> TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.RunImpl()    at
> TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommand.Run()    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CommandLine.CommandLine.RunCommand(String
> commandName, String[] args, Boolean& showExitCode)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CommandLine.CommandLine.RunCommand(String[]
> args)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CommandLine.CommandLine.Run(String[]&
> args)    at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandLine.Main(String[] args)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Did you find the answer to it ? I'm on 2020.0.1 and getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I can share a fix which helped us, but it might be a specific scenario fix. After the upgrade from Azure DevOps 2020.1 to 2020.1.1 (patch 4), this error has started to occur when running Migrator.exe validate. Fix was to add parameter (which was used only when running the "prepare" option):

```
Migrator.exe validate /collection:https://PathToADO/CollectionName /tenantDomainName:YourDomainName.onmicrosoft.com
```

Comment: This is the actual solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The error said you need to upgrade your on-premises server to  Azure DevOps Server 2020 or Azure DevOps Server 2020.0.1 first. Please try upgrading your on-premises server.

> Support for importing from Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1.1 has been removed. If you're currently on Azure DevOps Server 2019 Update 1.1, you will need to upgrade your on-premises server to Azure DevOps Server 2020 or Azure DevOps Server 2020.0.1